# Hibernate stored procedure result problem

Tags: hibernate, stored-procedures

I'm trying to call a stored procedure using Hibernate, but I'm getting the following exception all the time:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The column name plan_id was not found in this ResultSet.
```

The stored procedure is added as an auxiliary database object in one hbm.xml (actually this is the only XML mapping file I have, everything else is done with annotations):

```
<hibernate-mapping>
<database-object>
    <create>
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION copy_plan(p_plan_id bigint, p_plan_for_year varchar, p_copy_pp boolean)
RETURNS REFCURSOR
AS $$
DECLARE
    result REFCURSOR;
    // some more declarations
BEGIN
    // a lot of logic which works fine

    OPEN result FOR 
    SELECT  plans.plan_id as plan_id,
            plans.plan_for_year as plan_for_year, 
            plans.plan_plan_id as plan_plan_id, 
            plans.plan_f_type as plan_f_type, 
            plans.plan_enabled as plan_enabled
    FROM rgt_plans plans WHERE plans.plan_id = v_plan_id;

    RETURN result;

END;
$$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL
    </create>
    <drop>DROP FUNCTION copy_plan</drop>
</database-object>
```

The entity class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "rgt_plans")
@NamedNativeQueries({ @NamedNativeQuery(name = "copyPlan", query = "select copy_plan(:planId, :newYear, :copy)", resultClass=Plan.class) })
public class Plan implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -8448579977833577641L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "IdGenerator", strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
@TableGenerator(name = "IdGenerator", pkColumnValue = "rgt_plans", table = "Sequence_Table", allocationSize = 1)
@Column(name = "plan_id", columnDefinition = "int4")
private Long id;

@Column(name = "plan_for_year")
@NotNull
private String forYear;

@Column(name = "plan_plan_id")
@Basic
private Long plan_id;

@Column(name = "plan_f_type", length = 1)
@Basic
@NotNull
private String type;

@Column(name = "plan_enabled")
@Basic
@NotNull
private Boolean enabled;

// getters, setters, equals, hashcode

}
```

And thats how I call it from my DAO:

```
public List<Plan> copyPlan(Long currentPlanId, String newYear, Boolean copy) {
    return this.getHibernateTemplate()
            .findByNamedQueryAndNamedParam("copyPlan",
                    new String[] { "planId", "newYear", "copy" },
                    new Object[] { currentPlanId, newYear, copy });

}
```

As you can see I'm using PostgreSQL 8. Any ideas to why it's not working? I mean I'm returning everything from that table even with labels assiged...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well after much googling and cursing I got it running.

I had to change the @NamedNativeQuery to:

```
@NamedNativeQueries({ @NamedNativeQuery(name = "copyPlan", query = "{? = call copy_plan(:planId, :newYear, :copy)}", resultClass = Plan.class, hints = { @QueryHint(value = "true", name = "org.hibernate.callable") }) })
```

So I added a @QueryHint and changed the query itself.

I also had to ask @Transactional at the method in the DAO layer.