# Grails : how to customize order with a sql function?

Tags: grails, grails-orm, distance

I want to retrieve the 10 nearest geolocalized objects using Gorm.
To do so, I would like to customize the *order()* parameter in order to use a *get_distance(longitude, latitude, :longitude, :latitude)* sql function.
I've been struggling with this all day, does anybody have a hint ?

Thanks !

**EDIT**

I finally managed to do what I wanted but with a very ugly solution :

- I added a sqlProjection in which I put my get_distance() function and was able to order by it.
- Adding a projection removes the retrieval of the object properties so I had to explicitly ask for it by adding property projections and I managed to do it with introspection.
- Then I had to define the result transformer of the criteria for it to give me domain instances.

Answer (score 1):

If register your function with the hibernate SQL dialect, then you can use it in HQL queries.  For example, put this in your bootstrap code:

```
import org.hibernate.dialect.function.SQLFunctionTemplate
import org.hibernate.Hibernate

def dialect = applicationContext.sessionFactory.dialect
def getDistance = new SQLFunctionTemplate(Hibernate.INTEGER, "get_distance(?1,?2)")
dialect.registerFunction('get_distance', getDistance)
```

Then you can use it in HQL:

```
Location.executeQuery(
    """
        select id, get_distance(latitude, longitude) as distance 
        from Location
        order by distance
    """, 
    [], [max: 10])
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer ! The thing is I need to have the same behaviour but within a _createCriteria()_ query. Any idea ?

Comment: I think you can filter with the function in a criteria using `sqlRestriction` but I don't know of any way to use it for ordering.

Answer (score 0):

What we did is the following:

1. Create the query with whatever DB specific operators, but as a view
2. Create a new domain class object solely to map to the view, thereby allowing you to do GORM criteria queries and the like

Comment: Nice hack but I don't think it can apply to my case : my get_distance() function needs parameters as it calculates the distance from given coordinates : 
select * from Location l order by get_distance(l.longitude, l.latitude, :longitude, :latitude)

Comment: Ok.. I haven't worked with stored procs / functions in the DB for over a decade, and don't see any way other than the first to solve it.. You could try working it from the lower level Hibernate angle.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7183110/hibernate-stored-procedure-result-problem